# D3.js v5 schemeCategory library undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, undefined

I have been learning d3.js recently and am in the midst of creating a scatterplot that would make the each data point a different color based on their category. For this every resource I have looked at so far pointed me to use d3.schemeCategory for ordinal labelling.

My main issue is that the schemeCategory library seems to be undefined every time I call it (or any variation of it for that matter). I was wondering whether this is limited to me or if others have experienced this same problem as well.
**Please note** whenever I use `http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js/` or `~/d3.v5.js` I always get a MIME error. So I have been using the d3.js version 5 package that is downloadable from their website.

Here is a snippet of the code below for some context:

```
colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                        .domain(regionSet)
                        console.log(d3.schemeCategory20)
                        //.range(d3.schemeCategory20);
```

Where `regionSet` are the categories used. The output of the console.log command is simply `undefined`

Any and all feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> D3 no longer provides the d3.schemeCategory20* categorical color schemes. These twenty-color schemes were flawed because their grouped design could falsely imply relationships in the data: a shared hue can imply that the encoded data are part of a group (a super-category), while relative lightness can imply order. Instead, D3 now includes d3-scale-chromatic, which implements excellent schemes from ColorBrewer, including categorical, diverging, sequential single-hue and sequential multi-hue schemes. These schemes are available in both discrete and continuous variants.

From: [D3 Repo](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)

You should be using [D3 Scale Chromatic](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic) instead.